# List Of info, We Can Get From Visitor using PHP, Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, browser

As you know, Google and Facebook get lots of info about their visitors using different methods (except info that user give himself), so that they may serve website & ads according to user info. So I want a complete list of info, that we can get from our website visitors using PHP, JavaScript etc and if there are other methods.

Here are few things that I know & if you know anything else then kindly post in answer with its method. Thanks.

### PHP List:

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 
$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]; 
$_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"]; 
$_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]; 
$_SERVER["HTTP_VIA"];
$_SERVER["HTTP_XROXY_CONNECTION"];
$_SERVER["HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION"];
$_SERVER["HTTP_USERAGENT_VIA"];
$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"];
$_SERVER["REMOTE_HOST"];
$_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"];
$_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"];
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"];
$_SERVER["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"];
$_SERVER["HTTP_CACHE_INFO"];
$_SERVER["HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP"];
```

### Javascript List

```
screen.width
screen.height
```

Comment: You realise that Google gets much of their information from people who use Google Chrome right? As that sends a unique identifier to Google and no other data necessary.

Comment: Also, google mainly analyses what you input on http://google.com and on wich links you click on their page.

Comment: So in other words @Brianca, What Google and Facebook does is analyzing gathered data to build a profile. That data comes from user logins (or other means that Jonas mentioned) (don't forget google analystics, tracking you over mosts sites) which they'd use to build a profile around you. If you want the same, you'd have to gather unique data, header, ip and and then you can start binding data to profiles.

Answer (score 1):

The type of information you are seeking is usually referred to as browser fingerprinting. This is where you collect distinguishing information about a visitor in order to catalog and track your web site visitors without the use of cookies.

Here is a list of Javascript tracking information based on the fingerprintjs2 project (https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2)...

```
UserAgent
Language
Color Depth
Screen Resolution
Timezone
Has session storage or not
Has local storage or not
Has indexed DB
Has IE specific 'AddBehavior'
Has open DB
CPU class
Platform
DoNotTrack or not
Full list of installed fonts (maintaining their order, which increases the entropy), implemented with Flash.
A list of installed fonts, detected with JS/CSS (side-channel technique) - can detect up to 500 installed fonts without flash
Canvas fingerprinting
WebGL fingerprinting
Plugins (IE included)
Is AdBlock installed or not
Has the user tampered with its languages 1
Has the user tampered with its screen resolution 1
Has the user tampered with its OS 1
Has the user tampered with its browser 1
Touch screen detection and capabilities
Pixel Ratio
```

You should also read https://panopticlick.eff.org/static/browser-uniqueness.pdf as it will give further insight into server and client based fingerprinting and the available information provided by web visitors.